# Photos with pre-filled captions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, caption

We recently got the follow message from FB:

It looks like your app, [Our App Name] may be posting photos with pre-filled captions. If that's the case, you'll want to remove any default photo captions within the next few days in order to avoid restrictions...

We are not using the "caption" field, but some of the photos shared do have embedded images in the image itself wich we have no control over.

We also post a url in the "message" field that link User to more info about that media.

It is confusing to us what FB is talking about.

Also, we are a mobile App, thus this kind of change will take some time to do and pass through Apple submission and release cycle.

Any help is appreciated.

here is a sample of our posts:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s36/sh/9c5d091c-805e-4088-83b8-2d51f060a704/f06b36f9bddb1b200a4aaaa073eebc4c

Answer (score 0):

`We also post a url in the "message" field that link User to more info about that media.`

This is what you need to stop doing, it's explicitly against policy

Comment: Thanks, we will remove this url, but since our App is a iOS App, it will take us some time (a few weeks) to submit our next release update and go through the Apple review process.

Comment: What if I still want to have a link somewhere near the photo? Should I use comment for this? Plz advice.